# How to calculate fields in an oracle apex form in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-xe

I,m using Oracle XE 11g with an IR report and standard form.
So far I've managed the following in the report region,
QUANTITY - SOLD IN_STOCK
This works in the report but I get no result in the entry form. 
tried the same SQL in the source field of IN_STOCK but doesn't work. 
Also tried writing the calculated field into the table, but had no luck, examples I found didn't work. 
Any ideas would appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: You might get a good solution if you can re-create it on apex.oracle.com and show everyone the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The calculations you create on an interactive report are just for the report itself. If you need this field to be a value in the entry form or to be used outside of the report, you may need to define this derived column on the database table level.

This ref may be of help with respect to `virtual columns`:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/statements_7002.htm

Search this document for "virtual columns". A virtual column works like a IR calculation field, but it is recognized at the database level. See the section on restrictions if you have any trouble with setting up a virtual column.

With a virtual column, now, when you query the database for the calculated value to show in a form or query result, it will dynamically show it based on the two columns you specify in its definition.

Answer (score 0):

You need Dynamic Action

This a example:

**When**
Event : Change
Selection Type: Items
Items(s): fields in page separated with comma that participate on calculating

Example: P5_CORRELATIVO_DESDE,P5_NO_CAJAS,P5_DOCUMENTOS_X_CAJA

**True Actions**
Action: Set Value
[Action do Set Value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVo0J.png)

**Settings**
Set Type: PL/SQL Function Body
PL/SQL Code:

DECLARE
  ln_value NUMBER(12) := 0;
BEGIN
  IF :P5_CORRELATIVO_DESDE != 0 AND :P5_NO_CAJAS != 0 AND :P5_DOCUMENTOS_X_CAJA != 0
  THEN
     ln_value := ((:P5_CORRELATIVO_DESDE - 1) + ( :P5_NO_CAJAS * :P5_DOCUMENTOS_X_CAJA));
  END IF;

RETURN ln_value;
END;

Page Items to Submit: fields in page separated with comma that participate on calculating

Example: P5_CORRELATIVO_DESDE,P5_NO_CAJAS,P5_DOCUMENTOS_X_CAJA

Suppress Change Event: Yes

**Affected Elements**
Selection Type: item(s)
Item(s): page item for destiny of calculated value
Example: P5_CORRELATIVO_HASTA

[Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFrfj.png)

Top

Answer (score 0):

Prepare a function that calculates the second shot date based on the manufacturer
recommended number of days between shot

```
SHOT DATE 27 DAYS
```